# Google custom 404 page

Tags: html, css, styles, http-status-code-404

I would like to know what the property #goog-fixurl for the custom 404 widget is for as i cant find any documentation on it. i understand all of the other property style  #goog-fixurl

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is so that you can style them from your CSS document.

Take a look at [google webmasters bin](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=136085)  or  [style-the-google-404-widget random blog](http://www.crearegroup-webdesign.co.uk/blog/industry-news/style-the-google-404-widget.html)

Carry on

Comment: that was a quick response and exactly what i was looking for....thanks  for your help